# Reusing data entry methods across views

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikeyboard

I have written code for scrolling my table view even when keyboard hides it from entering data, using the notification center and the `keyboardDidShow` and `keyboardDidHide` methods.

The problem is that I have almost 8 views in my app where I need to enter some data.

Should I write the whole code in every single .m file, or is there any other easy way I could do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write some kind of `BaseTableViewController` which handles all the keyboard notifications.

Then let all the other TableViewControllers inherit from this base controller.

Answer (score 1):

Either you define that method in your application delegate file or create a separate class file which contains the method and you can call it whenever it required.

**myMethod.h file**

```
    @interface myMethod : NSObject 
    {
    }
    - (void) callMyMethod;
```

**myMethod.m file**

```
    - (void) callMyMethod
    {
         // your code
    }
```

In your view, call this method....

```
   myMethod *objMyMethod = [[myMethod alloc] init];
   [objMyMethod callMyMethod];
```

Answer (score 1):

The DRY ([Don't Repeat Yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) principal would lead to creating one set of code to handle the input, not many copies that do the same thing.

The principal of decoupling would lead to a separate class for the code.

A separate class would also allow easier Unit Test to be written.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a perfect use-case for a [category](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html).